# How to get request body in Spring Cloud Gateway and addHeader

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-cloud-gateway

I plan to migrate a project from Zuul to Spring Cloud Gateway.
I have a "checksum code" and I don't know how to migrate it.

In the zuul code i get the url parameter and json body, I then do some checks.

```
HttpServletRequest request = requestContext.getRequest();
Map<String, String[]> parameterMap = getURLParamter(request);
String json = getBody(request);

if(securityCheck(parameterMap, json) == true) {
    requestContext.addZuulRequestHeader("check-success-then-next-filter", "1");
} else {
    requestContext.setResponseBody("{ msg:: check error }");
}
```

I have limited experience with Spring gateway please help me find what the equivalent code is in Spring Gateway,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring Cloud gateway has filters to modify request body and response body.

[ModifyResponseBody](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/docs/current/reference/html/#modify-a-response-body-gatewayfilter-factory)
[ModifyRequestBody](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/docs/current/reference/html/#modify-a-request-body-gatewayfilter-factory)

As mentioned in the specs, for using these filters, we need to use DSL approach rather than YAML file for configuring routes. So essentially you will have a RouteBuilder like below -

```java
@Bean
public RouteLocator myRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
    RouteLocatorBuilder.Builder routeLocator = builder.routes().route(
    p -> {
      p.method("POST").path("/<path>").filters(f -> {
         f.modifyRequestBody(String.class, 
                             String.class,
                             (exchange, reqMessage) -> {
                try {
                    log.info(">>> INCOMING REQUEST <<< - {}", reqMessage);
                    //Get query params
                    exchange.getRequest().getQueryParams();
                    // In case of any validation errors, throw an exception so that 
                    // it can be handled by a global exception handler
                    return Mono.just(reqMessage);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.error("Exception while modifying request body", e);
                    throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
                }
            });
        })
    });
}
```

A global exception handler could then send a standard response back -

```java
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler {
    @Override
    protected RouterFunction<ServerResponse> getRoutingFunction (ErrorAttributes errorAttributes) {
       return RouterFunctions.route(RequestPredicates.all(),this::renderErrorResponse);
    }
    
    private Mono<ServerResponse> renderErrorResponse (ServletRequest request) {
        Map<String,Object> errorPropertiesMap = getErrorAttributes (request,ErrorAttributeOptions.defaults());
        String customErrMsg = errorPropertiesMap.get("message") != null ? errorPropertiesMap.get("message").toString() : null;
    
        if(customErrMsg != null) {
            return ServerResponse.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
                                 .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                                 .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(errorPropertiesMap.get("message")));
        } else {
            return ServerResponse.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
                                 .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                                 .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(errorPropertiesMap));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Cloud you provide the complete code ? I looked over this document and found it very abstract.  I try to used cacheRequestBody to read data . It looks like a @Bean has been injected Spring .but  how can I  handle the return result ？

Comment: This solution solves the part of accessing request body, but not the part of adding a headers depending of that content. Any tip for that? Maybe chaining two filters:
- ModifyRequestBodyGatewayFilterFactory
- AddRequestHeaderGatewayFilterFactory

Answer (score 1):

GlobalFilter can be used to modify the request.

```
public class RequestTransaformationFilter implements GlobalFilter, Ordered {

  @Autowired 
  private ModifyRequestBodyGatewayFilterFactory modifyRequestBodyFilter;
  @Autowired 
  private RequestBodyRewrite requestBodyRewrite;

  @Override
  public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
    return modifyRequestBodyFilter
        .apply(
            new ModifyRequestBodyGatewayFilterFactory.Config()
                .setRewriteFunction(String.class, String.class, requestBodyRewrite))
        .filter(exchange, chain);
  }

 
}
```

RequestRewrite bean can be configured to modify request:

```
public class RequestBodyRewrite implements RewriteFunction<String, String> {

  @Override
  public Publisher<String> apply(ServerWebExchange exchange, String body) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
   
      Map<String, Object> map = gson.fromJson(body, Map.class);
      map.put("NewField", "value");
      return Mono.just(gson.toJson(map, Map.class));
    
  }
}
```

Comment: is it necessary to declare a route for global filter?

Comment: I don't think we need a global filter, just a GatewayFilterFactory is enough. Baeldung has a good example of it: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway-response-body

Answer (score 0):

With the latest additions to [Spring-Cloud-Gateway v4](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/spring-cloud-gateway/gatewayfilter-factories/cacherequestbody-factory.html) you can utilize a CacheRequestBody to much more simply access request body without blocking operations.

In your application.yml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: my-id
          uri: https://my-host.com
          predicates:
            - Path=/path/**
          filters:
            - name: CacheRequestBody
              args:
                bodyClass: org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap
```

In your filter or apply method, you can now access your body using:

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> formData = exchange.getAttribute(ServerWebExchangeUtils.CACHED_REQUEST_BODY_ATTR);
```

For my case, I am expecting to recieve x-www-form-urlencoded so my bodyClass and form are MultiValueMap. It should be possible to do any format you expect.